# How can I find id in text to make a link in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am testing `<a href=# id="aaa">JQUERY</a>` one.

I want to add link for 'JQUERY' and deal with this using jQuery.

```
$(#aaa).click (function(){
   console.log('aaa');
});
```

Unfortunately, my code cannot find id("aaa") so that I get an error message. 
How can I make a link for this and then add function?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code, you're **missing quotes**.

```
$('#aaa').click (function(){
   console.log('aaa');
});
```

check [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/MZ4c5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use proper html and jquery code.

See DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/8ShJC/

## HTML (without space in front and back of a)

```
<a href="#JQUERY" id="aaa">JQUERY</a>
```

## JQUERY (with quote for element id or class)

```
$('#aaa').click (function(){
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```